# How to parse and take only this string value

Tags: objective-c

I wanted to get only array string value app. As example(SLGoogleAuth ,HalfTunes,TheBackgrounder,Calculiator) . But don't know how to do?
It's a code.

```
    @implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//    
    Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    SEL selector=NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");
    NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector]; 
    SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");
    NSLog(@"apps: %@", [workspace performSelector:selectorALL]);
}
```

It's output:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to parse that. NSLog prints out a description of an object. You want to access that value directly.

```
[LSApplicationWorkspace allApplications];
```

returns NSArray of LSApplicationProxy. LSApplicationProxy class has a ivar _bundleURL that contains information that you need. You need runtime functions to access it. Working example below:

```
    // #import <objc/runtime.h>
    Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    SEL selector=NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");
    NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector];
    SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");
    NSArray* appProxies = [workspace performSelector:selectorALL];

    Ivar bundleUrlIvar = class_getInstanceVariable([appProxies.firstObject class], "_bundleURL");

    NSMutableString* result = [NSMutableString string];
    for (id appProxy in appProxies)
    {
        NSURL* url = object_getIvar(appProxy, bundleUrlIvar);
        // at this point you have the information and you can do whatever you want with it
        // I will make it a list as you asked
        if (url)
        {
            [result appendFormat:@",%@", [url lastPathComponent]];
        }
    }

    if (result.length > 0)
    {
        // remove comma from beginning of the list
        [result deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    }


    NSLog(@"apps: %@", result);
```

Note that this will be rejected by AppStore as you are using private apis. So use at your own discretion.

Comment: Great thanks, maybe you know how to do tableview, because I don't understand how to do result in array

Comment: You have to find some tutorials online. https://www.raywenderlich.com/143828/macos-nstableview-tutorial

Comment: Can you help me in result I have array?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. If you want result variable to be an array. You just need to change it from `NSMutableString` to `NSMutableArray`. Instead of `appendFormat:` use `addObject:` and remove that last condition.